# jQuery - detect if div has 2 classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to detect a click like this..

```
$(".clickable_link").click(function() {
    console.log('Link Clicked');
}

<div class="clickable_link">
    Click Me
</div>

<div class="clickable_link special">
    Click Me
</div>
```

I am trying to determine if the div with 'special' has been clicked or if it just the div with 'clickable_link'.

What is the best way to do this? Should I use hasclass or is filter a better choice?

Comment: to check if the clicked element has a class : `$(this).hasClass('special')` , to add the event only to elemnts with two classes : `$('.clickable_link.special').click(...)`

Comment: Your question text does not quite match up with the title.  title: check if 2 classes.  text: check for specific class.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
$(".click").click(function(){
 if ($(this).hasClass("special")) {
  alert("Its Special!");
 }
});
```

```css
.click {
width:100px;
height:50px;
background-color:#333;
float:left;
margin:10px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
padding-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">Not Special</div>
<div class="click special">SPECIAL!</div>
```

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Yah I thought we were having a little bit too much fun, following the steps of a master, catch you later!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `.hasClass`, you can use `.is`, which allows for any selector, not just checking for a class.

```
if($(this).is(".special")) { ...
```

```js
$(".clickable_link").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(".special")) { 
    alert("special clicked");
  } else {
    alert("nope");
  }
});
```

```css
.special { color: red; }
.clickable_link { cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="clickable_link">
    Click Me
</div>

<div class="clickable_link special">
    Click Me
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#id1').click(function() {
  var x = $('#id1').attr('class') //dont use classname to fetch the element
  x = x.split(' ')
  if (x.length > 2)
    alert('id1 has more than 2 classes');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='id1' class='myclass mysubclass'>dfdfdfsdfds</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind different event handlers depending on whether the `special` class exists.

```
$(".clickable_link.special").click(function()
    console.log("Special link clicked");
})
$(".clickable_link:not(.special)").click(function() {
    console.log("Ordinary link clicked");
});
```

If there's common code for both types of links, you can put that in another function that gets called by each handler.

Answer (score 1):

As example, use can can detect count of classes as like it:

```
$(".clickable_link").click(function() {
    var classList = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    console.log(`count ${classList.length}`);
}
```